# element.nextElementSibling is not returning the right element

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using CKEditor 5 to create a text-rich editor on each `textarea` that has the `class` `.section-dynamique-fr`.

The editor is indeed appended to my html page.

Now, when I try to access the editor via javascript using `e.nextElementSibling`, it does not return its `nextElementSibling` as seen in the node tree from the console inspector, instead it returns `e.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling`.

Any idea why I can't access e.nextElementSibling? (the div with the `class` `.ck-editor`) ?

See attached image for html node structure

[image]

```
document.querySelectorAll('.section-dynamique-fr').forEach( (e) => {

    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector('#' + e.id), {
            // toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link' ]
        } )
        .then( editor => {
            window.editor = editor;
            thisEditor = editor;
        } )
        .catch( err => {
            console.error( err.stack );
        } );

    console.log(e); //This gives me the textarea
    console.log(e.nextElementSibling); //This should gives me the div with class ck-editor but instead gives me the div with class .textarea-saved-content-fr
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55261911/edit) and then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] instead of posting pictures of HTML

Comment: I figured it would be easier since I needed the CKEditor.js file to generate the correct html. Do I need to edit even if it was marked as duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because editor did not create after `create` execution. you need replace you code to `then`callback. `callback` is a `Promise` and it will be resolve after editor fully created. See [documentaion](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-classic_classiceditor-ClassicEditor.html#event-ready)

```
document.querySelectorAll('.section-dynamique-fr').forEach( (e) => {

    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector('#' + e.id), {
            // toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link' ]
        } )
        .then( editor => {
            window.editor = editor;
            thisEditor = editor;
            console.log(e.nextElementSibling);
        } )
        .catch( err => {
            console.error( err.stack );
        } );
```